# In the .gcov file generated by the gcov, what does the return statement contain an asterisk (*) mean?

Tags: gcov

I got a gcov file with a return statement marked as *, and I don't quite understand why?

Generally, a line is preceded by an asterisk: indicates that the line of code was executed, but not all of it was executed (for example, only part of it was executed in a loop). But my return statement has no other part, so why is it marked as an asterisk?

[image]

I've read the documents on the official website, but I still don't understand them.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov

Comment: Another question I have is why my line, line number 284, has two blocks.
=======================================================================
86*:  284:        return;
%%%%%:  284-block  0
86:  284-block  1